# Reasonable number of List <string> elements?

Tags: c#, sql, list, generics

I know there are limitations to the number of items that can be added to a List  (basically int.MaxValue), but what is a reasonable number to use in an everyday scenario - 100k, 500k, 1 million?

I'm using a DataReader and adding one string at a time to a List, then processing the elements as a batch. I want to ensure I'm not pushing memory limits too much by making the batches too large.

Comment: Depends on your machine and what you mean by processing it. Profile your code

Comment: How much memory do you have?  How big are the Strings in the list?  How can we answer your question without that information?

Comment: The answer is always 42

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to return an IEnumerable (not List) and use the `yield` keyword.  This will not consume extra memory for a list.

```
public IEnumerable<string> MyBigList(DataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       yield return (string) reader["SomeField"];
    }
}
```

In the old days this was called a co-routine, in C# its referred to as an iterator.  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) for more information on iterators and `yield`.

To process the string(s)

```
foreach (var s in MyBigList(reader))
{
   // do something with s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

The main idea behind the size of count of strings is that every character takes 2 bytes of memory by default.

Some considerations:

- If every string in a list is a full text of a classic novel, then 100 items can certainly bring some problems, but if this list is a dictionary of correctly spelled words of average 7-8 characters long, then 100k strings shouldn't be a problem since it's just a couple megabytes.
- How many of lists are you going to have? If it is a single instance, then it takes X bytes of memory. But if it is an ASP.NET application and you create a `List` for every user request, then it is going to grow exponentially.
- If you write an application for a powerful server station, then multiple-gigabyte cache collection can be a reasonable solution, but if you write a desktop client application with low system requirements, then you cannot afford it.
- If you make many scan operations (search), add and remove items, save it or load from file system, then every operation is taking `O(N)` operations. Probably, you would like to change used collection type according to your problem or use a database.
- If you process items one by one and you can avoid working with it as with collection, then you don't need `List` at all.
- etc.

In most cases, "What is the reasonable number of `List` items" question is not as critical as
**"Is this a reasonable case for using `List` at all?"**.
In-memory dynamic-size plain collections (i.e., `List`) can either be useful or useless in different usage scenarios, and we can't know which one is your case (especially, without your code).